# Error trying to run Sagan spring.io Project java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I have cloned `https://github.com/spring-io/sagan.git` and followed instructions [here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/wiki/Run-the-site-locally) to run it using ./gradlew: sagan-site:bootRun.
I tried it on a clean Ubuntu Desktop installation with Oracle JDK 8 as well as OpenJDK 8. Building it always fail with this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sagan.projects.support.$Proxy115 cannot access its superinterface sagan.projects.support.ProjectMetadataRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

demo-core module containing a non-public Spring Data JPA repository interface.

Note that there are many workarounds for this:

1. making the repository interface public
2. running the application from the IDE

and some other ways!!

For further updates u can in touch with:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4857

https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues/613